# browser automatic reload when index.html changes

Tags: webpack-dev-server

I am using `webpack-dev-server` in a very simple setup.
I've found that even though the server automatically triggers a browser reload when the `index.js` file changes, it does *not* trigger a reload when the `index.html` changes. How can I achieve that?

Here's my setup:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "html-reload",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
        "build": "node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8383 --content-base dist"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: 'dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
};
```

I launch the `webpack-dev-server` with: `npm run start` and I point my browser to:

```
http://localhost:8383/webpack-dev-server/index.html
```

Every change I made in `src/index.js` is automatically refreshed in the browser, but not so with changes I make in `dist/index.html`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally stumbled across *html-webpack-plugin* as described [in this guide](http://courses.reactjsprogram.com/courses/reactjsfundamentals/lectures/762538).

I run:

```
npm i -D html-webpack-plugin
```

And edited my *webpack.config.js* to look like this:

```
'use strict';
const path = require('path');

const APPDIR = 'app/';

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.resolve(__dirname, APPDIR, 'index.html'),
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});

const config = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, APPDIR),
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/')
            },{
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['style', 'css']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};

module.exports = config;
```

The "template" `index.html` file now resides in my `app` directory and upon building the project a generated `index.html` file is placed in the `build` directory. The latter file contains the correct reference to the bundled output file `bundle.js` (this is the only difference between the two files).

"Template" *index.html* file in *app*:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://localhost:8090/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='app'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Generated output *index.html* file in *build*:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://localhost:8090/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='app'></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Now, when running `webpack-dev-server` changes to `index.html` are also immediately refreshed in the browser.
This being said, the `index.html` being so minimal, the use case for editing it and wanting the edits to automatically refresh the browser seems trivial.
Nevertheless, it feels better that `index.html` resides in my `app` directory as opposed to the `build` directory.

Comment: Marcus, thanks a lot. You saved my time. I've been struggling with this for a while since last night.