# How to create single page web application with typescript and webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, webpack

I have been creating single page applications in Angular for some time, and now I would like to create a single page application but without using the entire framework.

I would like to have one .html file, and one javascript file, which would be compiled typescript file, say `index.ts`. And inside `index.ts` I would import things from other typescript files.

Are there any projects online which are similar to what I want to achive, and is it possible to setup npm project like this at all?

Edit:

After some time, this is what I accomplished:
My project structure:

```
├── bundle.js
├── functions.ts
├── index.html
├── index.ts
├── package.json
├── style.css
├── tsconfig.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "rxjs6-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.1",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2",
    "webpack": "^4.27.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": ".",
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "module": "es6",
      "target": "es6",
      "allowJs": true
    },
    "include": ["*.ts"],
    "exclude": []
}
```

webpack.config.json

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: '.'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]
  }
};
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

running `npm start` will start a webpack-dev-server which recompiles my application each time any typescript file changes. Inside index.ts I can import stuff from other .ts files. But what I couldn't accomplish is making webpack-dev-server reload my app in the browser when html or css files change.

Any help or general suggestions about the structure of my application will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the current setup, Webpack is not processing your `.html` and `.css` files, so it stands to reason that it's also not monitoring them for changes. Rather than adding `link` tags into your `.html` file for the `.css` files, you can instruct Webpack to process the `.css` files using `css-loader` and `style-loader`.

First, you need to install `css-loader` and `style-loader`. e.g.:

```
npm i -D css-loader style-loader
```

`css-loader` is responsible for processing CSS files and `style-loader` is responsible for injecting them into the DOM. When using this approach, the output `bundle.js` (in your example) will contain the transpiled JavaScript and the CSS, with the CSS itself being wrapped up in JavaScript and DOM manipulation.

Next, you need to add a rule to `webpack.config.js`:

```json
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
}
```

This rule, which sits in the `rules` array alongside your existing `ts-loader` rule, instructs Webpack to process `.css` files first using `css-loader` and then `style-loader`.

Lastly, you can add an import into your `index.ts` file:

```
import './style.css';
```

That should be all that's needed for Webpack to start processing and monitoring your `.css` file. For additional files, you can add more `import` statements as shown above.

As for `.html` files, there's a good answer for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37446767) that should help. There's also a great tutorial/online book on the styling topic (and almost everything else you could need) by SurviveJS [here](https://survivejs.com/webpack/styling/loading/). The book also covers things like building for production, which allows for extracting the CSS content out into a separate file for production builds, etc.